# Rails program duplicate rows on database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql-9.1

I have a problem with a ruby on rails application that connects with database postgreSQL 9.1.

I have an apllication when I click to save info, this duplicates the row on the database.

I was searching for any duplicated code on my program but I can't see nothing.

Can someone help me?

The view part:

```
 <fieldset>
        <legend>Opciones Generales</legend>
        <dl>
            <dt><%= l.label :name %></dt>
            <dd><%= l.text_field :name %></dd>
            <dt><%= l.label :highlight %></dt>
            <dd><%= l.text_area :highlight, :class => 'editor' %></dd>
            <dt><%= l.label :content %></dt>
            <dd><%= l.text_area :content, :class => 'editor' %></dd>
        </dl>
     </fieldset>
      <% end %>
     <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "#{smart_label(request.fullpath)}", :class => 'btn green' %>
     </div>
```

Controller part:

```
def create
post = Post.new(params[:post])
  if post.save
    flash[:notice] = "El post se ha creado correctamente."
    @page = post.widget.page
  end
  @object = post
  render 'widgets/create'


end
```

I think that in model there's nothing interesting, but I can paste if you need.

log of inserts:

```
Started POST "/backend/posts" for ***.***.***.*** at 2015-05-04 11:37:40 +0200
Processing by PostsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"****=", "post"=>{"widget_id"=>"8", "homepage"=>"1", "active"=>"1", "translations_attributes"=>{"1"=>{"id"=>"", "locale"=>"ca", "name"=>"prueba", "highlight"=>"<p>hola<br></p>", "content"=>"<p>hola<br></p>"}, "2"=>{"id"=>"", "locale"=>"es", "name"=>"", "highlight"=>"", "content"=>""}}}, "commit"=>"Ejecutar"}
  [1m[36mCustomer Load (1.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "customers".* FROM "customers" WHERE "customers"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 3]]
  [1m[35mLang Load (0.8ms)[0m  SELECT "langs".* FROM "langs" WHERE "langs"."customer_id" = 3 AND "langs"."default" = 't' LIMIT 1
  [1m[36m (0.5ms)[0m  [1mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (1.9ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "posts" ("active", "created_at", "header", "homepage", "updated_at", "widget_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["active", true], ["created_at", Mon, 04 May 2015 09:37:40 UTC +00:00], ["header", nil], ["homepage", true], ["updated_at", Mon, 04 May 2015 09:37:40 UTC +00:00], ["widget_id", 8]]
  [1m[36mSQL (1.6ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "post_translations" ("content", "created_at", "highlight", "locale", "meta_description", "meta_keywords", "name", "post_id", "slug", "title", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11) RETURNING "id"[0m  [["content", "<p>hola<br></p>"], ["created_at", Mon, 04 May 2015 09:37:40 UTC +00:00], ["highlight", "<p>hola<br></p>"], ["locale", "ca"], ["meta_description", nil], ["meta_keywords", nil], ["name", "prueba"], ["post_id", 286], ["slug", "prueba"], ["title", nil], ["updated_at", Mon, 04 May 2015 09:37:40 UTC +00:00]]
  [1m[35mSQL (0.8ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "post_translations" ("content", "created_at", "highlight", "locale", "meta_description", "meta_keywords", "name", "post_id", "slug", "title", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11) RETURNING "id"  [["content", ""], ["created_at", Mon, 04 May 2015 09:37:40 UTC +00:00], ["highlight", ""], ["locale", "es"], ["meta_description", nil], ["meta_keywords", nil], ["name", ""], ["post_id", 286], ["slug", ""], ["title", nil], ["updated_at", Mon, 04 May 2015 09:37:40 UTC +00:00]]


 [select ... ]
  Rendered widgets/_list.html.erb (33.9ms)
  Rendered widgets/create.js.coffee (1475.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1540ms (Views: 1356.5ms | ActiveRecord: 164.5ms)


Started POST "/backend/posts" for ***.***.***.*** at 2015-05-04 11:37:42 +0200
Processing by PostsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"********=", "post"=>{"widget_id"=>"8", "homepage"=>"1", "active"=>"1", "translations_attributes"=>{"1"=>{"id"=>"", "locale"=>"ca", "name"=>"prueba", "highlight"=>"<p>hola<br></p>", "content"=>"<p>hola<br></p>"}, "2"=>{"id"=>"", "locale"=>"es", "name"=>"", "highlight"=>"", "content"=>""}}}, "commit"=>"Ejecutar"}
  [1m[36mCustomer Load (0.9ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "customers".* FROM "customers" WHERE "customers"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 3]]
  [1m[35mLang Load (0.7ms)[0m  SELECT "langs".* FROM "langs" WHERE "langs"."customer_id" = 3 AND "langs"."default" = 't' LIMIT 1
  [1m[36m (0.4ms)[0m  [1mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (0.9ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "posts" ("active", "created_at", "header", "homepage", "updated_at", "widget_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["active", true], ["created_at", Mon, 04 May 2015 09:37:42 UTC +00:00], ["header", nil], ["homepage", true], ["updated_at", Mon, 04 May 2015 09:37:42 UTC +00:00], ["widget_id", 8]]
  [1m[36mSQL (1.0ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "post_translations" ("content", "created_at", "highlight", "locale", "meta_description", "meta_keywords", "name", "post_id", "slug", "title", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11) RETURNING "id"[0m  [["content", "<p>hola<br></p>"], ["created_at", Mon, 04 May 2015 09:37:42 UTC +00:00], ["highlight", "<p>hola<br></p>"], ["locale", "ca"], ["meta_description", nil], ["meta_keywords", nil], ["name", "prueba"], ["post_id", 287], ["slug", "prueba"], ["title", nil], ["updated_at", Mon, 04 May 2015 09:37:42 UTC +00:00]]
  [1m[35mSQL (0.8ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "post_translations" ("content", "created_at", "highlight", "locale", "meta_description", "meta_keywords", "name", "post_id", "slug", "title", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11) RETURNING "id"  [["content", ""], ["created_at", Mon, 04 May 2015 09:37:42 UTC +00:00], ["highlight", ""], ["locale", "es"], ["meta_description", nil], ["meta_keywords", nil], ["name", ""], ["post_id", 287], ["slug", ""], ["title", nil], ["updated_at", Mon, 04 May 2015 09:37:42 UTC +00:00]]
  [1m[36mPost::Translation Load (0.9ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "post_translations".* FROM "post_translations" WHERE "post_translations"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 564]]
  [1m[35mPost::Translation Load (0.7ms)[0m  SELECT "post_translations".* FROM "post_translations" WHERE "post_translations"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 565]]
  [1m[36m (19.8ms)[0m  [1mCOMMIT[0m
```

The insert is executed in 2 seconds of difference.

Could anyone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: What's your app log? Are there two post requests going to server?

Comment: Yes, two posts. Question edit.

Comment: Double check and make sure you don't have any `before_create` or `after_create` triggers on your model that are coded to save new objects. At one point I saw someone who was using the callbacks to create the object that was triggering the callback, thus duplicating the record (and having some...odd recursion problems at the same time)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your form:

```
<dt><%= l.label :name %></dt>
<dd><%= l.text_field :name %></dd>
<dt><%= l.label :highlight %></dt>
```

shouldn't it be:

```
<%= l.submit "#{smart_label(request.fullpath)}", :class => 'btn green' %>
```

for your submit?
However `<% end %>` suggests you somehow nest your form, so feel free to post your complete form.

As Marek mentioned, some logs for your `create` action would be of great help.

---

What is the desired response for your create action? if you want to call views/posts/create.js try to add this to your `create` action:

```
def create
  post = Post.new(params[:post])
  respond_to do |format|
    if post.save
      format.js { layout: false }
      flash[:notice] = "El post se ha creado correctamente."
      @page = post.widget.page
    end
 end
 @object = post
 render 'widgets/create'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all thanks.

I saw looking logs that the create was executing in 2 times, after I saw in firebug that there are 2 post calls.

Looking the firebug there was 2 jquery in the application, because of this the creation was executing twwice.

When I delete the jquery in application.js the error was corrected.

Thank you for all!